# Excel - Rolling Average on multiple Sheets #Value Error

Tags: excel, rolling-average

I am trying to get average on
Sheet#1 as Data entered from sheet 2- sheet13 For example :
Output result should be rolling average of Cell - G2 from Sheet 2 - Sheet13 
Every month Data added and result should change as rolling average.
following syntax gives #value error
=IF(Data2!G2=" "," ",AVERAGE(Data!G2:Data1!G2))
in this case i am trying to Skip Sheet - Data2  and retrive result of average Sheet - Data +Data1

Thankyou

Comment: You have the range as Data!G2 to Data1!G2. Is that across two sheets or your error?

Comment: Data!G2:Data1!G2 is the range -Which need to average every month . Example (Jan-Dec)

Comment: I was able to figure out the results